# Filtering nested lists using lambda

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

I am having a `List<User> users`. I would like to filter the list basing on two conditions.

1. Matching the UserID
2. Matching the FilterName

   public class User implements Entity {

   ```
       public User() {
       }

       private String userName;
       private String userId;
       private List<Filter> filters;

       public String getUserName() {
           return userName;
       }

       public void setUserName(String userName) {
           this.userName = userName;
       }

       public String getUserId() {
           return userId;
       }

       public void setUserId(String userId) {
           this.userId = userId;
       }

       public List<Filter> getFilters() {
           return filters;
       }

       public void setFilters(List<Filter> filters) {
           this.filters = filters;
       }

   }
   ```

Here is the method signature

```
List<User> users = getUsersList();
public List<User> query(String userID,String filterName){
    users.stream().filter(element -> element.getUserID().equals(userID) && element.getFilters().stream().filter(f -> f.getFilterName().equals(filterName))).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

The above method does not work as i am filtering basing on a element and a stream. Can anybody help me with the right way of filtering lists and nested lists.

I also tried this way

```
users.stream().filter(e -> e.getUserId().equals(predicate.getUserID())).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().filter(f -> f.getFilters().stream().filter(fe -> fe.getName().equals(predicate.getFilterName()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

either ways i am getting the below error

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream to boolean**

Tried Adiel Loingers suggestion. It worked

```
java.util.function.Predicate<Filter> con = e -> e.getName().equals(predicate.getFilterName());
            result = users.stream().filter(p -> p.getUserId().equals(predicate.getUserID()) && p.getFilters().stream().anyMatch(con)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What about using `anymatch` on the filterName stream?

Comment: If you want to check `filterName` present in the Filter List or not. You can simply change `element.getFilters().stream().filter(f -> f.getFilterName().equals(filterName))` to `element.getFilters().stream().filter(f -> f.filterName.equals(FilterName)).findAny().isPresent()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shall change

```
element.getFilters().stream().filter(f -> f.getFilterName().equals(filterName))
```

to

```
element.getFilters().stream().anyMatch(f -> f.getFilterName().equals(filterName))
```

which would return `boolean` true for any match of the predicate specified which is same as specified in `filter` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may help you, second conditions gets stream of all filters and find your filter name present in that filter is list, if so returns true otherwise false.

```
users.stream()
        .filter(element -> element.getUserId().equals(userId)
            && element.getFilters().stream().filter(f -> f.filterName.equals(FilterName)).findAny().isPresent())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```